# Pyspark join and operation on values within a list in column

Tags: python, join, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have two dataframes, namely

```
df1 = sc.parallelize([
  ['u1', 'type1', ['a', 'b']],
  ['u2', 'type1', ['a', 'c', 'd']],
  ['u1', 'type2', ['d']]
]).toDF(('person', 'type', 'keywords'))

df2 = sc.parallelize([
  ['a', 2],
  ['b', 1],
  ['c', 0],
  ['d', 1],
  ['e', 3],
]).toDF(('keyword', 'score'))
```

I need to calculate, for each `person` and per `type`, the average `score` of its `keywords`. So, this average would be 1.5 for `person` 'u1' on `type` 'type1' as it has keywords 'a' and 'b' which contribute with 2+1/2=1.5

I have tried an approach encompassing a join:

```
df = df1.join(df2) \
  .select('person', 'type', 'keywords', 'keyword', 'score') \
  .groupBy('person', 'type') \
  .agg(avg('score'))
```

but the problem is, it is computing the average on each possible keyword, not solely on those which said user and type have, so that I obtain 1.4 everywhere, which is the sum of all scores for all keywords divided by their number.
I need to sum up only scores for those keywords in the list `keywords` per user and type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to `explode` the `keywords` first:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, avg, col

(df1.select("person", "type", explode("keywords").alias("keyword"))
    .join(df2, "keyword")
    .groupBy("person", "type")
    .agg(avg("score")))
```

While it could be possible to do something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

(df1.join(df2, expr("array_contains(keywords, keyword)"))
    .groupBy("person", "type")
    .agg(avg("score")))
```

to achieve the same result it is something you want to avoid in practice to avoid expansion into a Cartesian product.